# Writing Timestamp to Cloud Firestore from Dart

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm trying to write a DateTime to Cloud Firestore as a Timestamp and it doesn't work if I try to add a `List<String, dynamic>`, the date just shows up as a String value in Firestore.

For example, if I have a `User` class:

```
class User {
  final String name;
  final DateTime birthday;

  User(this.name, this.birthday)
}
```

and I write it like this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("users").add({
  "name":user.name, 
  "date":Timestamp.fromDate(user.birthday)
})
```

it works fine and the date shows up correctly in Firestore as a Timestamp type.

However if I try to create a `Map<String, dynamic>` and add it:

```
class User {
  ...
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      "name": name,
      "date": Timestamp.fromDate(birthday)
    }
  }
}
```

And write it like this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("users").add(user.toMap())
```

then it shows up as a String in Firestore instead of a Timestamp.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Try `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

Comment: Since you say that `"date":Timestamp.fromDate(user.birthday)` works, why can't you use that?

Comment: @Volleyball that will set the timestamp to the current time on the server which is clearly not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to write a birthdate.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I can but I like the cleanliness of having a `toJson()` function in the object class.

Comment: @odiggity Sorry I misunderstood that.